# Calculate millions adjacent records and summarize them in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Id like to calculate millions of adjacent records and summarize them in the end in Elasticsearch. How can I do this?

Documents (six of them) data in Elasticsearch:

```
10
20
-30
10
30
100
```

Calculation:

```
  10  to  20 is  10
  20  to -30 is -50
 -30  to  10 is  40
  10  to  30 is  20
  30  to  100 is 70
```

The total is:

10 + (-50) + 40 + 20 + 70 = 90

How would I do a query with REST - RestHighLevelClient API to achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Generic case

Most likely the only reasonable way to do this in Elasticsearch is to [denormalize](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html) and put into Elasticsearch already computed deltas. In this case you will only need a simple [sum](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) aggregation.

This is because data in Elasticsearch is "flat", so it does not know that your documents are adjacent. It excels when all you need to know is already in the document at index time: in this case special indexes are pre-built and aggregations are very fast.

It is like [A'tuin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discworld_(world)), a flat version of Earth from Pratchett's novels: some basic physics, like `JOIN`s from RDBMS, do not work, but magic is possible.

### Time series-specific case

In case when you have a time series you can achieve your goal with a combination of [Serial Differencing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-aggregations-pipeline-serialdiff-aggregation.html) and [Sum Bucket](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html) [sibling aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-aggregations-pipeline.html).

In order to use this approach you would need to aggregate on some date field. Imagine you have a mapping like this:

```
PUT time_diff
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "eventTime": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "val": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And a document per day which look like this:

```
POST /time_diff/doc/1
{
  "eventTime": "2018-01-01",
  "val": 10
}

POST /time_diff/doc/2
{
  "eventTime": "2018-01-02",
  "val": 20
}
```

Then with a query like this:

```
POST /time_diff/doc/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_date_histo": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "eventTime",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "the_sum": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "val"
          }
        },
        "my_diff": {
          "serial_diff": {
            "buckets_path": "the_sum"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "my_sum": {
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "my_date_histo>my_diff"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response will look like:

```
{
  ...
  "aggregations": {
    "my_date_histo": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1514764800000,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "my_delta": {
            "value": 10
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    "my_sum": {
      "value": 90
    }
  }
}
```

This method though has obvious limitations:

- only works if you have time series data
- only correct if you have exactly 1 data point per date bucket (a day in example)
- will explode in memory consumption if you have many points (millions as you mentioned)

---

Hope that helps!